# Caliburn Micro - wp8.1 prevent backkeypress

Tags: caliburn.micro, windows-phone-8.1

I don't understand how to prevent the backkeypress in the CaliburnMicro 2.0.0 (wp8.1).
With the beta version I handled the event inside the view with the NavigationHelper. But now it doesn't work.
What is the best practice now?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `NavigationHelper` executes `GoBackCommand` no matter how `e.Handeled` is set. Try to edit your `NavigationHelper` class and add check-up in `if` statement of `HardwareButtons_BackPressed`:

```cs
private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    // if (this.GoBackCommand.CanExecute(null)) // this is as a default
    if (this.GoBackCommand.CanExecute(null) && !e.Handled) //  add a check-up
    // ... rest of the code
```

Also check your App.xaml.cs file, and remove susbscription if there is one - this event is fired as first:

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
  //  HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed; // this line also fires frame.GoBack() (as default project template)
}
```

Comment: Yes I already updated the event like you. But the navigation goes back. It seems there is something more... I don't understand

Comment: @Tiziano Then also check your App.xaml.cs like in my edit. Default project my already have a subscription which is fired as first.

Comment: With caliburn I don't have that event in App(). Maybe is something in caliburn framework?

Comment: @Tiziano Maybe, you will have to look/debug more. I'm run out of ideas without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in Caliburn.Micro not checking to see if the event has already been handled.